# adding json data using taffydb in durandal

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal, taffydb

I'm trying to use taffydb with durandal. I'm able to add simple json-data to a ko.observableArray() (a colleague showed me how :-) ).

Now I want to save it using taffydb.

main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
   'taffy': '../lib/db-master/taffy'
    ...
  }
});
```

participant.js:

```
define(['durandal/app', 'knockout', 'models/user', 'taffy'], function (app, ko, user, taffy) {
...
}
```

Whenever I add this:

```
var db = taffy;
db.insert({record:1, data:"test"});
```

I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined

Leaving it out will add test-data as expected. Am I 'holding' durandal the wrong way?

regards
Claus

Comment: Have you console.log'd taffy before you call .insert on it?  Adding require.js tag to your question, as this is a require.js question more than likely.

Comment: I added console.log(taffy) and it's 'undefined'. console.log(ko) shows [object Object]. So it looks like it's not loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [this code](https://github.com/typicaljoe/taffydb/blob/master/taffy.js) is the one you are loading, then you need a [shim](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) in the configuration you pass to RequireJS because taffy is not AMD-aware. I believe this should work:

```
shim: {
    taffy: {
        exports: "TAFFY"
    }
}
```

I've never used taffy so I'm not aware what its dependencies might be. You might need to add a `deps: [...]` field to the shim so that the dependencies are loaded ahead.

Comment: Awesome. Works. Yeah. :-)